# Automating software installation where window is rebooting multiple times

Tags: autoit

How can I automate a software installation using AutoIt where window is rebooting multiple times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this:

1. Add your installation script to autostart
2. After every Step, write your status to a file
3. After reboot read the file and continue at correct position
4. When finished, stop or even delete your script _selfdelete